# Kivy - changing button color on press

Tags: python, kivy

I've recently started using [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) to design GUI for my python app. In the app one of the actions is sending requests to server using provided API. After a couple of tests I've noticed one annoying thing that happens only when I want to make a request - the button doesn't change color on press (I'm talking about default action). However, it is changing when simple `print()` is used.

How I can fix it? Any idea?

This is the code of my test app:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        btn = Button(text='Add')
        btn.bind(on_press=self.add)
        parent.add_widget(btn)
        return parent

    def add(self, obj):
        print("Adding")
        request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
        urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened most likely because the UI froze. The`self.add` is called, but right after that the UI waits until the request is done, which for you might result in that.

Try to do it like this:

```
import threading

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        btn = Button(text='Add')
        btn.bind(on_press=self.add)
        parent.add_widget(btn)
        return parent

    def add(self, obj):
        print("Adding")
        #self.printer()  # freezing
        threading.Thread(target=self.printer).start()

    def printer(self, *args):
        while True:
            print 'blob'
TestApp().run()
```

Also, instead of `on_press` use rather `on_release`. Prevents accidental events if I remember correctly (checks for collision touch↔button area).

Comment: Thank you for answer, but unfortunately now it is not triggering the method at all. The button is changing color correctly.

Comment: @sebap123 see the edit. Thread prevents freezing UI. If the request doesn't work, that's a problem of the request/your code.